What is the most efficient method to map indices to required set of numbers?
In a bit of C++ code, I am iterating through an array with indices (0-7) and require the best way to compute the given set of values a and b from some function taking i as input.
i:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
---------------------------
a: -1  1 -2  2  1 -1  2 -2
b:  2  2  1  1 -2 -2 -1 -1 

The obvious solution is to use if statements. With a bit of digging and math, this is the best I could come up with-
int a = (i%4 == i%2) ? (!(i>=4 ^ i%2) ? -1 : 1) : (!(i>=4 ^ i%2) ? -2 : 2);
int b = (i%4 == i%2) ? (i>=4 ? -2 : 2) : (i>=4 ? -1 : 1);

I find this code to be very clunky and would like to know the most optimized way to do the same.

Please define the criteria of  "the most efficient method".

If you're looking up lots of times, you may be able to use ssse3 intrinsic as a look-up table. See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ssetechs=SSSE3&ig_expand=6003

General rule of thumb: Never ask for most, best, etc... on Stack Overflow. They are rapidly moving targets that require you to write up a full specification document for the system, and the answers you get are pretty much useless to anyone else asking the same question. Plus no one in real life pays you to provide most or best. They pay you for good enough to meet requirements.

Why not just using 2 basic arrays? This is fast on all recent mainstream (x86-64) CPU as long as data is in the cache. For example, since at least Intel Skylake (2015) and AMD Zen (2017), you can load 2 items per cycles (with a latency of 3-4 cycle in the L1). Your convoluted code is inefficient and also need to fetch data from the cache too... A simple array access should be always better on such CPU. This should also be true on most ARM architectures. Keep it simple first (see KISS) and then profile to optimize for this on the target CPU.

The obvious solution is to use if statements -- I disagree -- the obvious solution is to create a table of the output values and just index the table.  You know beforehand what the output values are for every value of i, so why go through the process of computing anything?

I'd go with constexpr arrays of pairs, or an c-array and struct, or any combi of these.
Totally untested code
using PairsArray = std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 8>;
constexpr PairsArray PA {
  { -1,2 }, { 1,2 }, { -2, 1 }, {2, 1} // and so on
}

constexpr int DoStuff(int i) {
  return PA[i].first*3+PA[i]*-2;
}

Potentially calculating the calls to DoStuff if it can be done at compile time.
